# Add a module in in ES6 using import instead of require

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hi I am trying to add a module to my code. In ES5 I used

```
var promise = require('bluebird');
```

So I tried `import { promise } from 'bluebird'` but it didn't work any idea why?

Comment: `import Promise from 'bluebird'` should do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually `import { promise } from 'bluebird'` translated in es5 as `var promise = require('bluebird').promise`. So the equivalent of `var promise = require('bluebird')` in es6 would be `import * as promise from 'bluebird'`

EDIT: Based on the comment of @Bergi: `import Promise from 'bluebird'` is a more simplified version.

Answer (score 16):

Generally to use `import` instead of `require` we should use some external modules, because `Node.js` doesn't support ES6's import yet.

To do so, we first have to install those modules `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-cli`.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-cli
```

Then we create a dot file called `.babelrc` where we add inside of it this object :

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Now we will be able to use `import` instead of `require`. For example, we can try on some `server.js` file this peace of code where we call `express` module using `import` instead of `require`:

```
import express from 'express'; //instead of const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/',function (req, res){
    res.send('hello from import');
});

app.listen(4444, function(){
    console.log('server running on port 4444');
});
```

Finally in our shell we will have to run this command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node app.js --presets es2015
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Greeter.js` (put it into `Scripts` folder):

```
export class Greeter() {
    constructor() {

    }

    getGreeting() {
        alert('Hello from the greeter class');
    }
}
```

Call it:

```
<script>
    import {Greeter} from "/Scripts/Greeter.js";

    let greeter = new Greeter();
    greeter.getGreeting();
</script>
```

Comment: What does `Greeter` have to do with Bluebird?

Comment: @Bergi Oh sorry, I just give an example how to call a module via using `import` keyword.

Comment: @HappyCoding I used bluebird just an example. So it is alright.

Answer (score 0):

Use this flag: `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node`

```
node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node index.js
```